# Formula to copy and paste only the bold cell from a cell range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets workbook and I need to have only the bold item from a range of cells be copied and pasted automatically into a cell on a different sheet. I have found info on how to separate bold text from within a cell, but not how to automatically pull out the one bold cell from the rest and paste it in a specific place on another sheet.

For example, if I had

```
Sheet 1, cell A1: Giraffe
Sheet 1, cell A2: **Iguana**
Sheet 1, cell A3: Alligator
Sheet 1, cell A4: Monkey
```

And I want **Sheet 2**, cell **G25** to equal the bolded cell from range **A1:A4** on **Sheet 1**. What would the formula for that be? Is that possible?

Comment: why is the cell bolded? it's easier to do this based on the "why" than the font style

Comment: This is a Google Sheet to be shared with clients. They are asked to list several answers to a question and then to bold the answer that is most important to them. I then want the one they bold to autofill in a cell on another sheet. If there is a better way to accomplish this, I'm definitely open!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `how to automatically pull out the one bold cell from the rest and paste it in a specific place on another sheet.` and `And I want Sheet 2, cell G25 to equal the bolded cell from range A1:A4 on Sheet 1.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?